# Como exibir um conteúdo html em um dataTable

Tags: java, jsf, rich-faces

Possuo o campo mensagem em um Editor que depois da inclusão é mostrado em um dataTable.

```
<rich:editor value="#{solicitacaoImpressaoBean.solicitacao.mensagem}" toolbar="full"  style="margin-bottom: 1em">
```

DataTable:

```
<rich:dataTable id="tabelaSolicitacoes" value="#{solicitacaoImpressaoBean.peg.solicitacoes}" var="solicitacao"
            iterationStatusVar="it" rowClasses="linhaPar, linhaImpar"
            style="width: 100%;"
            >

            <rich:column style="text-align: center;">
                <f:facet name="header">Data</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{solicitacao.dataEnvio}" converter="dataHoraConverter"  />
            </rich:column>

            <rich:column style="text-align: center;">
                <f:facet name="header">Siape do Cadastrador</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{solicitacao.siapeCadastrador.siape}" />
            </rich:column>

            <rich:column style="text-align: center;">
                <f:facet name="header">Assunto</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{solicitacao.assunto}" />
            </rich:column>

            <rich:column style="text-align: center;">
                <f:facet name="header">Mensagem</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{solicitacao.mensagem}" />
            </rich:column>
```

O problema é que o editor insere o código da mensagem em html e depois de incluido irá mostrar o html inserido.

Ex do campo mensagem :`<h1>Teste de inclusao na <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif">Mensagem Enviar Solicita&ccedil;&atilde;o</span> para a peg 4415</h1>`

## Teste de inclusao na Mensagem Enviar Solicitação para a peg 4415

Como posso mostrar este conteúdo no dataTable da mesma forma que escrevi no Editor, ou seja sem as tags html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O padrão do `JSF` é fazer o escape de tags de `HTML` e `XML`, o que precisa fazer é desabilitar isso.

Para a tag [`outputText`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/outputText.html) basta definir o atributo `escape` para `false`:

```
<h:outputText escape="false" value="#{solicitacao.mensagem}" />
```

Comment: E como manter a formatação ? por ex <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif"